# What is the origin of a NestedServletException?

Tags: java, spring, filter, sap-commerce-cloud

Lately I've been working with the Hybris platform and I encountered an exception in my Tomcat today. The issue is I can't seem to find any valuable information about what a NestedServletException is or why it's thrown. At the moment my priority is to understand the concept, then after solve it.

In case it's usefull, I'll attach the StackTrace:

```
Estado HTTP 500 - Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 5 of 15. Current filter: 'es.logista.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter@539dc64a'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

type Informe de Excepción

mensaje Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 5 of 15. Current filter: 'es.logista.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter@539dc64a'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 5 of 15. Current filter: 'es.logista.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter@539dc64a'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:234)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:89)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)

causa raíz

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.PersistenceInfoCache.getCachedExternalTableTypes(PersistenceInfoCache.java:70)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.getExternalTableTypes(DBPersistenceManager.java:883)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.typecache.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.getExternalTableTypes(DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.java:137)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:93)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:78)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.createSingleType(FromClause.java:89)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translateNested(FromClause.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText$2.translate(ParsedText.java:269)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchTools.replace(FlexibleSearchTools.java:310)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText.translate(ParsedText.java:263)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translate(FromClause.java:48)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.translate(ParsedQuery.java:401)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.getTranslatedQuery(ParsedQuery.java:181)
    de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.QueryParser.translateQuery(QueryParser.java:229)
    de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.translate(FlexibleSearch.java:2007)
    de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1412)
    de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1628)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:374)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:1)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSessionService.executeInLocalView(DefaultSessionService.java:91)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.getJaloResult(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:363)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.search(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:164)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.dao.AbstractItemDao.search(AbstractItemDao.java:70)
    de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.daos.impl.DefaultCMSSiteDao.findAllCMSSites(DefaultCMSSiteDao.java:42)
    de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.services.impl.DefaultCMSSiteService.getSites(DefaultCMSSiteService.java:317)
    de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.services.impl.DefaultCMSSiteService.getSiteForURL(DefaultCMSSiteService.java:269)
    de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.context.impl.DefaultContextInformationLoader.initializeSiteFromRequest(DefaultContextInformationLoader.java:98)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.processNormalRequest(CMSSiteFilter.java:161)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:89)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    es.logista.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)

nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario de Apache Tomcat/7.0.59.
```

Comment: The root cause is the fact that you get a `NullPointerException`. Which is somewhere in your chain wrapped in a `NestedServletException`.

Comment: You need to run a system update, you modified the typesystem but your db is not aware of the change, so your'e getting a null pointer from a flexible search query.

Comment: @Juan we eventually found out that we had to initialize the system... stupid of us, but thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nested Exceptions are exceptions wrapped up in another exception. People do that for multiple reasons (some of them mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955693/5529417)).

As you can see in the stack trace the `root exception` is a `nullpointer exception`.

So basically your `NestedServletException` is nothing but a `NullpointerException` that is caught & thrown again at some point, but wrapped up in a `ServletException`.

Comment: Thanks @Seth! Seen that way it seems pretty obvious, but it hadn't come up to my mind :)