# Catching messages thrown by classes in a lower level

Tags: scala

There are four levels in my application: (1) My application, (2) pivot4j, (3) olap4j, and (4) Mondrian

If I run this code in Scala:

```
try {
     renderer.render(model, new HtmlRenderCallback(sw)) 
}
catch {
  case ex: Exception => println(ex.getMessage)
}
```

The application prints the error thrown by pivot4j:

```
org.olap4j.OlapException: mondrian gave exception while parsing query
```

If I don't catch the error, the stack trace is (in bold the relevant messages):

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: **Execution
>   exception[[PivotException: org.olap4j.OlapException: mondrian gave
>   exception while parsing query]]**
>   at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
>           at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
>           at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
>           at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
>           at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
>           at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
>           at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36) **Caused
>   by: org.pivot4j.PivotException: org.olap4j.OlapException: mondrian
>   gave exception while parsing query**
>           at org.pivot4j.impl.PivotModelImpl.getCellSet(PivotModelImpl.java:598)
>           at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer.render(TableRenderer.java:425)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap.doRunMdx(RunOlap.scala:91)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap$$anonfun$runMdx$1.apply(RunOlap.scala:53)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap$$anonfun$runMdx$1.apply(RunOlap.scala:51)
>           at login.Authentication$LoggedAction$$anonfun$invokeBlock$1.apply(LoggedAction.scala:47)
>           at login.Authentication$LoggedAction$$anonfun$invokeBlock$1.apply(LoggedAction.scala:42)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36) **Caused
>   by: org.olap4j.OlapException: mondrian gave exception while parsing
>   query**
>           at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jConnection$Helper.createException(MondrianOlap4jConnection.java:858)
>           at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement.parseQuery(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:375)
>           at mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jStatement.executeOlapQuery(MondrianOlap4jStatement.java:346)
>           at org.pivot4j.impl.PivotModelImpl.executeMdx(PivotModelImpl.java:646)
>           at org.pivot4j.impl.PivotModelImpl.getCellSet(PivotModelImpl.java:596)
>           at org.pivot4j.ui.table.TableRenderer.render(TableRenderer.java:425)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap.doRunMdx(RunOlap.scala:91)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap$$anonfun$runMdx$1.apply(RunOlap.scala:53)
>           at olap.process.RunOlap$$anonfun$runMdx$1.apply(RunOlap.scala:51)
>           at login.Authentication$LoggedAction$$anonfun$invokeBlock$1.apply(LoggedAction.scala:47)
>
> **Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error: MDX object '[Measures].[Unit Cost]' not found in cube 'Sales'**

Mondrian is the one that is originating the error, and I need to get the message that is throwing:

```
 MDX object '[Measures].[Unit Cost]' not found in cube 'Sales'
```

I tried:

```
try {
     renderer.render(model, new HtmlRenderCallback(sw)) 
}
catch {
  case ex: MondrianException => println(ex.getMessage)
}
```

But is not catching the error.

Comment: you can do something like `try { ... } catch { case ex:OlapException => println(ex.getCause) }`

Comment: and AFAIK, there's no elegant way to catch nested exception in JVM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955458/catching-an-exception-that-is-nested-into-another-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Apache Commons [ExceptionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getRootCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29) to get the root exception.