# Unable to catch TransactionSystemException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have an Entity class Person which is connected to another entity Address via JoinColumn and has OneToOne relation with Person, the Address entity has a @NotNull annotation on field country.

Simplified Code is below:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long PersonId; 

@Valid
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;
....
..some more fields, getters and setters etc..
...
}
```

The Address entity is below:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long addressId;

private String street;

@NotEmpty(message = "Country should be there")
private String country;

....some more fields and getters and setters etc ....
}
```

Other than that i have a PersonRepository.

I also have a service method i.e updateAddress, the simplest form of the method is below:

```
public class Service {

@Transactional
public void updateAddress(Long personId, Address address) {
try {
Person original = findPersonById(personId);

...some validations etc ....

original.setAddress(address);            
personRepository.save(original);
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

    }
}
```

I have written one small unit test where i am trying to update the address using updateAddress method for a person having no predefined Address.

i.e

```
@Test
void checkUpdateAddress() {
Person person = new Person();
.....initiate some fields, except address ....
Long personId =personRepository.save(person);

Address address = new Address();
address.street("abcd");

service.updatePerson(personId, address);
//assertions etc
}
```

The problem is that i get

> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation
>   failed for classes [com.foor.bar.Address]
>   during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
>   List of constraint violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Country should be there',
>   propertyPath=country, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.foo.bar.Address,
>   messageTemplate='Country should be there'}
>
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction

I have tried using try/catch block, but still unable to catch this exception.

Note: i have simplified the codes to the minimal extent, if there is something i've forgotten or if my problem is unclear then do ask.

EDIT:

Full stack stace

> ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl:39 - HHH000346: Error during managed
>   flush [Validation failed for classes
>   [com.foo.bar.Address] during persist time
>   for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Country should be there',
>   propertyPath=country, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.foo.bar.Address,
>   messageTemplate='Country should be there'} ]]
>
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction
>
> at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
>     at
>   com.foo.bar.service.Service$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57d9106c.updateAddress()
>     at
>   com.rfoo.bar.service.MyTest.checkUpdateAddressMethod(MyTest.java:956)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing
>   the transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
>     ... 63 more Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Validation failed for classes
>   [com.foo.bar.Address] during persist time
>   for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Country should be there',
>   propertyPath=transactionId, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.foo.bar.Address,
>   messageTemplate='Country should be there'} ]  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:205)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:82)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
>     ... 64 more

Comment: Where is your @Service annotation? isn't it necessary?

Comment: @R.A.Munna no it's not necessary

Comment: Once you caught the exception you throw it again... why???

Comment: my bad, copy/paster error

Comment: So when you have a generic catch block what is the exception type being thrown?

Comment: Catching a `ConstraintViolationException` is a... weird idea. Anyway, try adding an explicit flush (using `personRepository.flush()` or `personRepository.saveAndFlush(original)`). Also, I'd use the more generic `catch(Exception e)` first to see what is the actual exception type

Answer (score 2):

Try catching `PersistenceException`. This exception is a wrapped exception and is not directly thrown. You can extract the wrapped `ConstraintViolationException` using the `getCause()` method.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the `ConstraintViolationException` is not being caught is that the repository is not throwing that exception, it is throwing `TransactionSystemException`, which has a nested `ConstraintViolationException` instance.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955458/catching-an-exception-that-is-nested-into-another-exception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more information on catching nested exceptions.

Comment: tried to catch TransactionSystemException  but didn't help.

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: added it, kindly check

Comment: 'The reason the `ConstraintViolationException` is not being caught is that the repository is not throwing that exception, it is throwing `TransactionSystemException`'. Umm... no. The reason the `ConstraintViolationException` is not being caught is that the repository is not throwing any exception *at all*, since validation only occurs at transaction commit, which is *after* `updateAddress` ends